# How to get the selected foreign key's value?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
   name = [...] # unique
   quantity = [..integer_field..]

class Sales(models.Model):
   sold_to = [...]
   sold_item = foreign key to Item
   sold_quantity = [..integer field..]
```

I want to make sure that if the selected Item has the quantity of 5, and you pass 6 or more to the `sold_quantity`, throw a `validation error` saying *"You have only X in stock and wanted to sell Y".*
I tried to override the save method, but however I try to do so, it changes nothing. When I try to access `self.sold_item`, it returns the name of the selected item.

When I try to do `item.objects.get(name=self.sold_item)`, whatever I do it returns just the name of the item and I can't access other fields (known as Quantity).

Conc:
`Item.objects.get(name=self.sold_item)` returns the name of the item.
using the same but Filter instead of Get returns a queryset, which contains <Item: the items name> and I can't access other fields of it.

Comment: have you tried this `self.sold_item.quantity` ? you can just check `if self.sold_item.quantity < self.sold_quantity: raise ....`

Comment: oh my god it works... Thank you... I really should recap on data types at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per a comment on the question, this is the answer

> have you tried this `self.sold_item.quantity` ? you can just check if `self.sold_item.quantity < self.sold_quantity: raise ....`